# Client err: `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` resp: { "err": "invalid_grant", "err_description": "Bad Req" }

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have been using google/googleapi package to work on google calendar when I request authorization on oauth2.0 I'm getting an error as

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }
```

I really need to fix this as soon as possible.

Here's my code for authentication, I've given Stack Trace for more clarification below the code.

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('vendor/credentials.json');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
    $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

    $rurl = action('gCalendarController@oauth');
    $client->setRedirectUri($rurl);
        
    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $filtered_url = filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        return redirect($filtered_url);
    } else {

        $refresh_token = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

        $request->session()->put('access_token',$refresh_token);

        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();

        $calendar->setSummary('Driving GradeBook');
        $calendar->setTimeZone('America/New_York');
    
        $createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);

        return redirect()->route('cal.index');
    }
```

Here's a link for Stack Trace of the same issue as above https://flareapp.io/share/w5BApNA7

Please, Help me out with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: One of the reason I have seen this is when the the parameters being passed are not in the right format. Maybe using the OAuth2.0 Playground or Postman could give a way to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for the response @SrinathMenon actually the error was occurring due to some changes which I did externally in the code. apart from that, the code above is working perfectly.

Comment: Based on your latest comment, did your issue get solved? If that's the case, please consider posting an answer explaining what the issue was and how it was solved.